# is there a function to re arrange the keys and values of an array base on another array?

Tags: php, arrays

let's say i have 2 array.

```
array1:
value = 2
value = 1
value = 3

array2:
value = 1
value = 2
value = 3
value = 4
```

i want to re arrange array1 to have the same sorting has array2 and remove the values that are not found in array2. I want to follow the sorting of array2 i dont know if there is an existing function for this if there is kindly tell me. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array1 = array(2,1,3);
$array2 = array(1,2,3,4);
$array_intersect = array_intersect($a2, $a1);
```

`$array_intersect` will then have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```